IN works slow without explicit data
This query:
select id
from user u
where u.account_id = 600

returns:
61,71,68,69,70,118,116,117,248,381,384,325,265,393

and it works really fast. This query:
select *
from logs l
where l.user_id in 
(
    61,71,68,69,70,118,116,117,248,381,384,325,265,393
)

works really fast too. But this query:
select *
from logs l
where l.user_id in 
(
    select id
    from user u
    where u.account_id = 600
)

works very slow (I'm getting a timeout). Why does putting explicit data solve the problem?
Edit
@Frank Heikens suggested another query with EXISTS, but it is slow as my version. Here is the output of ANALYZE of Frank's suggestion:
Hash Join  (cost=2.26..7411225.89 rows=29616999 width=146) (actual time=16817.855..55713.074 rows=19 loops=1)
  Output: l.log_vps, l.log_type, l.user_id, l.log_data_id
  Inner Unique: true
  Hash Cond: (l.user_id = u.id)
  Buffers: shared hit=12766 read=4130999 dirtied=1738
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..6904561.39 rows=184048493 width=146) (actual time=0.018..38769.019 rows=183943865 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=12765 read=4130999 dirtied=1738
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2022_08 l_1  (cost=0.00..1.33 rows=33 width=150) (actual time=0.017..0.024 rows=33 loops=1)
              Output: l_1.log_vps, l_1.log_type, l_1.user_id, l_1.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=1
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2022_09 l_2  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_2.log_vps, l_2.log_type, l_2.user_id, l_2.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2022_10 l_3  (cost=0.00..77.39 rows=2539 width=129) (actual time=0.009..0.277 rows=2539 loops=1)
              Output: l_3.log_vps, l_3.log_type, l_3.user_id, l_3.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=52
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2022_11 l_4  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_4.log_vps, l_4.log_type, l_4.user_id, l_4.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2022_12 l_5  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_5.log_vps, l_5.log_type, l_5.user_id, l_5.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_01 l_6  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_6.log_vps, l_6.log_type, l_6.user_id, l_6.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_02 l_7  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_7.log_vps, l_7.log_type, l_7.user_id, l_7.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_03 l_8  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_8.log_vps, l_8.log_type, l_8.user_id, l_8.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_04 l_9  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=732) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: l_9.log_vps, l_9.log_type, l_9.user_id, l_9.log_data_id
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_05 l_10  (cost=0.00..28481.43 rows=911143 width=136) (actual time=0.042..126.951 rows=911143 loops=1)
              Output: l_10.log_vps, l_10.log_type, l_10.user_id, l_10.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=19274
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_06 l_11  (cost=0.00..85697.79 rows=2741479 width=136) (actual time=0.023..385.662 rows=2741483 loops=1)
              Output: l_11.log_vps, l_11.log_type, l_11.user_id, l_11.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=58187
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_07 l_12  (cost=0.00..95413.89 rows=3052689 width=136) (actual time=0.033..412.469 rows=3052669 loops=1)
              Output: l_12.log_vps, l_12.log_type, l_12.user_id, l_12.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=64791
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_2023_08 l_13  (cost=0.00..134309.17 rows=4434017 width=128) (actual time=0.035..591.562 rows=4435031 loops=1)
              Output: l_13.log_vps, l_13.log_type, l_13.user_id, l_13.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=89873
        ->  Seq Scan on public.log_default l_14  (cost=0.00..5640260.93 rows=172905893 width=147) (actual time=0.018..23713.945 rows=172800967 loops=1)
              Output: l_14.log_vps, l_14.log_type, l_14.user_id, l_14.log_data_id
              Buffers: shared hit=12328 read=3898874 dirtied=1738
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.09..2.09 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=89.290..89.293 rows=14 loops=1)
        Output: u.id
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1
        ->  Seq Scan on public.user u  (cost=0.00..2.09 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=89.270..89.277 rows=14 loops=1)
              Output: u.id
              Filter: (u.account_id = 600)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 73
              Buffers: shared hit=1
Settings: search_path = 'public, public, "$user"'
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=18
Planning Time: 1.677 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 9
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.502 ms, Inlining 5.563 ms, Optimization 52.318 ms, Emission 31.147 ms, Total 91.530 ms
Execution Time: 55716.122 ms


Why not?: select * from logs AS l  join user AS u  on l.user_id = u.id where  u.account_id = 600.

You might have mentioned from the start that logs is a partitioned table. Please consider instructions for performance questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

In the first case, PostgreSQL knows what the values will be when it plans the query, so it can get a good estimate for the number of result rows.
In the second case, PostgreSQL doesn't have this information when the query is planned, so it uses an estimate. That estimate is off (30 million estimated rows vs. 19 actual rows), which causes PostgreSQL to choose a bad query plan.
There is probably a skew in the data of logs, with some user_ids having many rows and others few rows, and unless PostgreSQL knows which 14 rows get returned by the subquery, it cannot get the numbers right.
You could force PostgreSQL to perform a nested loop, which should get you the performance you need:
SELECT l.*
FROM user AS u
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT *
                       FROM logs
                       WHERE logs.user_id = u.id
                       OFFSET 0) AS l
WHERE u.account_id = 600;

OFFSET is useless per se, but keeps PostgreSQL from optimizing the subquery.
Note that while that plan may be faster for account_id 600, it might be slower for other values.

So what can I do about it? I tried analyze logs, but it didn't help

@HamBurg  For more input, please show the plans for both forms of the query (the literals, and the subquery).

You can rewrite this query and use EXISTS:
SELECT *
FROM logs l
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 42
    FROM user u
    WHERE u.account_id = 600 AND u.id = l.user_id
);

And the indexes, these will be beneficial:
CREATE INDEX idx_user_account_id_id ON user (account_id, id);
CREATE INDEX idx_logs_user_id ON logs (user_id);

After the changes, check the query plan using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement.

Hi, Unfortunately this is slow as my version. I added analyze to yours query

Lower your setting for random_page_cost, for example to 1.1 This could change the query plan, to use the indexes. And you did create them, right?

You should run the query like this and make sure that l.user_id is indexed.
select l.*
from logs l, user u 
where l.user_id = u.id
and u.account_id = 600


Hi, thanks for a suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help

At least use a proper JOIN syntax, that's in the SQL standard since the '90s last century.

You should have been started by saying that the table logs is a partitioned table. If you read the execution plan, you can see that no indexes are used. This is why your query is so long.
